# Why my eye ball materials disappeared?

Tags: materials, add-on, asset

[image]I used the tiny eye add-on but when I opened it in my project it looked different.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The cornea of the eye is translucent and uses the *Transmission* setting of the *Principled BSDF* shader node. It's similar to a glass shader.

For rendering with *Eevee* and for the *Material Preview* mode this requires that the `[X]` *Screen Space Reflections* and `[X]` *Refraction* options in the render settings are enabled.

Also don't forget the lighting so you can see the eye clearly.

[image: screen space reflections and refraction settings]